# How to set Barcode dimensions with barcodelib library

Tags: java, barcode

I'm working on generating EAN-13 barcodes using the Java barcode generation library from barcodelib.com. I've set the X dimension to 3 and the Y dimension to 75:

```
barcode.setUOM(Linear.UOM_PIXEL);
barcode.setX(3f);
barcode.setY(75f);
```

However, when the image is created, the width is set as 345 pixels, and the height is set as 99 pixels at 96 dpi. I'm trying to understand the relationship between the X and Y dimensions I've set and the resulting pixel dimensions. How does the library calculate the pixel dimensions based on the specified X and Y dimensions? Are there any default settings or algorithms influencing this? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What dimension, in pixels, do you want the bar code to be?  I suspect that the barcode library expects certain aspect ratios.  As examples,some grocery barcodes are twice as wide than high.

Comment: I want a barcode where width and height are configurable at the user's end. The user can create an image frame by specifying the width and height, and based on the details specified, the barcode should be generated. If there is a standard ratio that should be maintained, validation can be added. However, as mentioned in the question I posted above, width and height conversion from the values I provide to pixels is not directly proportional. I want to gain an understanding of the same.

Comment: The [Java Barcode Generation Guide](https://www.barcodelib.com/java_barcode/barcode_symbologies/java_barcode_generator.html) doesn't mention an EAN-13 bar code.

Comment: It is mentioned at https://www.barcodelib.com/java_barcode/barcode_symbologies/ean13.html. I believe that setting the X (for barcode module width) adjusts the width of the thinnest bar in the barcode, not the width of the entire barcode. This is what confused me.